# How to make a link's path change each day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, link-to

I am going to be posting daily workouts on my website. I want to put a link in the navbar that says something like "Today's workout". I will be creating the workouts beforehand and then I wanted the link's path to be to the show page of the current day's workout. I've never done anything like this so I don't really know the process.

I have a column `scheduled_on` as the date I want it to be published. Is there a way to make the link's path push to the `scheduled_on` date?

Comment: This is my theory not sure if it works for you, how about you create a hash with `date` as `key` and `value` as the `link`. And then compare the date(keys) with today's date and if it's today it'll return the respective `link`. You can run this as a cron and run it at every 24th hour.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Hmm, I feel like that might be unnecessary. I was thinking something like `<%= link_to_if Workout.scheduled_on == Date.today, "Today's Workout" %>` or something. And i've tried some of those variations but I keep getting **undefined method 'scheduled_on'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do easily by using below code

```
<% workout = Workout.where(scheduled_on: Date.today).first %>
<%= link_to_if(workout.scheduled_on == Date.today, "Today's Workout", Workout.find_by_id(workout.id) )  %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had `<%= link_to "Today's Workout", workout_path(id: Date.today) %>` and that seemed to work because I'm using the FriendlyId gem where the slug is the date of the workout. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Thank for your response please mention my answer right if it is useful for you.
Workout.friendly.find(params[:date]) can work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper method, which finds and returns the desired workout:

```
def todays_workout
    Workout.find_by_scheduled_on(Date.today.to_s).url
end
```

Then you can call the helper method in the link tag:

```
<%= link_to todays_workout, "Today's workout" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate route and keep the link path constant:

```
# routes.rb
resources :workouts do
  get :todays, on: :collection
end


# app/controllers/workouts_controller.rb
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def todays
    @workout = Workout.where(scheduled_on: Date.today).first
    # you can choose between redirecting 
    redirect_to @workout
    # or rendering
    render :show  
  end
end

# in the view
<%= link_to 'Latest Workout', todays_workouts_path %>
```

The reason I would create a separate route vs having a "dynamic" link is the possibility of caching the response in reverse proxy for performance. And having the logic of which is todays workout in the controller and not in the view.

Comment: thank yo for the response! I'm always looking for performance improvements.

Comment: I have been using @max 's answer and it's been working great.